# Bash: Pass alias or function as argument to program

Tags: bash, function, alias

Quite often i need to work on the newest file in a directory.

Normally i do:

```
ls -rt
```

and then open the last file in vim or less.

Now i wanted to produce an alias or function, like

```
lastline() {ls -rt | tail -n1}
# or
alias lastline=$(ls -rt | tail -n1)
```

Calling lastline outputs the newest file in the directory, which is nice.
But calling

```
less lastline
```

wants to open the file "lastline" which doesn't exist.

How do i make bash execute the function or alias, if possible without a lot of typing $() or ``?
Or is there any other way to achieve the same result?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're parsing `ls`, and this is very bad. Moreover, if the last modified “file” is a directory, you'll be `less`ing/`vim`ing a directory.

So you need a robust way to determine the last modified file in the current directory. You may use a helper function like the following (that you'll put in your `.bashrc`):

```
last_modified_regfile() {
    # Finds the last modified regular file in current directory
    # Found file is in variable last_modified_regfile_ret
    # Returns a failure return code if no reg files are found
    local file
    last_modified_regfile_ret=
    for file in *; do
        [[ -f $file ]] || continue
        if [[ -z $last_modified_regfile_ret ]] || [[ $file -nt $last_modified_regfile_ret ]]; then
            last_modified_regfile_ret=$file
        fi
    done
    [[ $last_modified_regfile_ret ]]
}
```

Then you may define another function that will `vim` the last found file:

```
vimlastline() {
    last_modified_regfile && vim -- "$last_modified_regfile_ret"
}
```

---

You may even have `last_modified_regfile` take optional arguments: the directories where it will find the last modified regular file:

```
last_modified_regfile() {
    # Finds the last modified regular file in current directory
    # or in directories given as arguments
    # Found file is in variable last_modified_regfile_ret
    # Returns a failure return code if no reg files are found
    local file dir
    local save_shopt_nullglob=$(shopt -p nullglob)
    shopt -s nullglob
    (( $# )) || set .
    last_modified_regfile_ret=
    for dir; do
        dir=${dir%/}
        [[ -d $dir/ ]] || continue
        for file in "$dir"/*; do
            [[ -f $file ]] || continue
            if [[ -z $last_modified_regfile_ret ]] || [[ $file -nt $last_modified_regfile_ret ]]; then
                last_modified_regfile_ret=$file
            fi
        done
    done
    $save_shopt_nullglob
    [[ $last_modified_regfile_ret ]]
}
```

Then you can even alter `vimlastline` accordingly:

```
vimlastline() {
    last_modified_regfile "$@" && vim -- "$last_modified_regfile_ret"
}
```

Comment: Thanks - for the examples. An impressive piece of code :)

Comment: @sargas Glad it helped. Now you have to study it to learn as much as you can from it! good luck `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use command substitution like this:

```
lastline() { ls -rt | tail -n1; }
less "$(lastline)"
```

Or pipe it to `xargs`:

```
lastline | xargs -I {} less '{}'
```

Comment: [More info on command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)